# sed rpm_install_prefix in rpm specfile

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I have tried to replace an expression in a file by $RPM_INSTALL_PREFIX in %post part of SPEC file. I used below command

```
sed -i "s/opt/$RPM_INSTALL_PREFIX/" /etc/mersad.conf
```

as I have respected it should change opt by the prefix which I use at installation. Unfortunately, it shows an error and doesn't do it. it just goes wrong in sed command and when I echo $RPM_INSTALL_PREFIX it shows the correct value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a different find-replace separator than '/' in the sed command option. Try using '|' as that is unlikely to be found in $RPM_INSTALL_PREFIX paths.

Note that you will likely encounter other problems (on upgrade in particular) if attempting to use --relocate: relocations are not persistent through upgrades.

Comment: I used below command and problem sad solved.
      sed -i "s!opt!$RPM_INSTALL_PREFIX!" /etc/mersad.conf